# What is wrong with the way I have made the array?

Tags: c, arrays

This program is for a project to help my students learn Spanish. I already had some great help. I have a problem when using the compiler. The errors are:

1)**Question** does not name a type

2)s_questions Undeclared (first use this function)

Is there an easy fix to these problems or are there some big problems with the code structure?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define arrsize(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

struct Question
{
       char quiz[130];
       char answer1[20];
       char answer2[20];
       char answer3[20];
       char answer4[20];
       int correctAnswer;
       bool used;
}

 static Question s_questions[]={
       {
                "Que significa la palabra 'ser'\n",
                "1. to do",
                "2. to be",
                "3. to make",
                "4. to understand",
                2,
                false
        },
```

Comment: Missing ; mark after struct }?

Comment: Also, try `static struct Question s_questions[]` or use `typedef`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Let's enumerate the problems:

1. `Question` is not a valid type in your code. `struct Question` is.
2. You're missing a semicolon after the definition of `struct Question`.
3. You have an extra semicolon in your `arrsize()` macro. And a missing parentheses.
4. To use `bool`, you must `#include <stdbool.h>`.
5. You didn't close your declaration of `s_questions`.

#### Fixing all of that would give us:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define arrsize(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

struct Question
{
    char quiz[130];
    char answer1[20];
    char answer2[20];
    char answer3[20];
    char answer4[20];
    int correctAnswer;
    bool used;
};

static struct Question s_questions[] = {
    {
        "Que significa la palabra 'ser'\n",
        "1. to do",
        "2. to be",
        "3. to make",
        "4. to understand",
        2,
        false
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

simple, First point - 
you miss the semi colan at the end of the struct

```
struct Question
{
       char quiz[130];
       char answer1[20];
       char answer2[20];
       char answer3[20];
       char answer4[20];
       int correctAnswer;
       bool used;
};
```

use this.
And other point is you shouds use "struct Question", Ex -

```
struct Question foo;
```

Else, use this typedef

```
typedef struct
{
       char quiz[130];
       char answer1[20];
       char answer2[20];
       char answer3[20];
       char answer4[20];
       int correctAnswer;
       bool used;
} Question;
```

Now you can use,

Question q;

Answer (score 1):

In C, a `struct` type variable must be declared using the `struct` keyword.
So change this line:

```
static Question s_questions[]={
```

to

```
static struct Question s_questions[]={
```

Additionally, after defining a `struct`, `union`, or `enum` type, you must put a semicolon after the closing brace.

```
struct Question
{
   char quiz[130];
   char answer1[20];
   char answer2[20];
   char answer3[20];
   char answer4[20];
   int correctAnswer;
   bool used;
}; //right here
```